# Alternate proof of Baby Rudin Theorem 6.9

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Theorem 6.9 of Baby Rudin states:  if $f$ is monotonic on $[a,b]$ and if $α$ is continuous then $f \in \mathscr R(\alpha)$ ($α$ is assumed monotonic). Here is a try at an alternate proof of above theorem in case f is monotonic increasing or decreasing:

Let $f$ be monotonic increasing. Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ with
$a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n=b\\U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^n (f_i^M-f_i^m)(\alpha(x_{i+1})-a(x_i))\\=\sum_{i=1}^n(f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i))(a(x_{i+1})-a(x_i))$
The last step follows from $f$ being monotonic increasing.
So $U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)=U(P,\alpha,f)-L(P,\alpha,f)$
Now from Theorem 6.8 of baby rudin $\alpha \in \mathscr R(f)$, so that a for any arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ partition $P$ can always be found so that $U(P,\alpha,f)-L(P,\alpha,f)<\epsilon$. The same partition will do for $f$ with respect to $\alpha$. Any comments appreciated.

Comment: What's $\mathscr R(\alpha)$? Is it the space of Riemann-Steiljes integrable functions with respect to $\alpha$? You should be more explicit here since the notation is not so standard.

Comment: @BigbearZzz You are correct in respect of notation. I'm following the notation followed by rudin. $\mathscr R(\alpha)$ is the space of Riemann-Steiljes integrable functions with respect to $\alpha$

Comment: Your statement of Theorem 6.9 of Baby Rudin is not complete. You only have the "if" statement and no "then" statement.

Comment: @xpaul it is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct. However a more general result is true:

**Integration by Parts**: *If $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$ then $\alpha \in \mathscr{R}(f)$ on $[a, b]$ and $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,d\alpha(x) + \int_{a}^{b}\alpha(x)\,df(x) = f(b)\alpha(b) - f(a)\alpha(a)$$*

The proof is not difficult and given in Theorem 7.6 in *Mathematical Analysis* by Tom M. Apostol, page 144. Note that the above general theorem does not add any conditions on $f$ or $\alpha$ like continuity or monotone nature.

Comment: But $\alpha$ is non decreasing and continuous and $[x_i, x_{i+1} ] $ is closed.  This guarantees that $\alpha_i^M=\alpha(x_ {i+1} $

Comment: @somitra: it appears that I did not read that part about $\alpha$. Will update answer accordingly.

Comment: Multan dankon pro la literatur-referenco. Mi supren-voĉdonis vian respondon.